# How to find the Surface Area?

Tags: vector-analysis

Find the surface area of the paraboloid
    $z = x^2+y^2$ that lies inside of the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 4$.

I keep getting $\frac{\pi}{6} (17\sqrt{17} - 1)$

This is how I did it:

[image]

Comment: How is your calculation set up?

Comment: I bound the integral by x^2+y^2= 4. I paramertaize z = x^2+y^2 which is S(r,theta) = <rcos(theta), rsin(theta), r^2> .

Comment: I then use the formula to do ||Sr cross Stheta|| . Then I do the intergal.

Answer (score 1):

$dS$ is defined by the surface of the paraboloid

$dS = (-\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},-\frac {\partial z}{\partial y},1)\\
\frac {\partial z}{\partial x} = 2x, \frac {\partial z}{\partial y} = 2y
$

$\iint ||dS|| \,dy \,dx\\
\iint \sqrt{4x^2 + 4y^2 + 1} \,dy \,dx$

limits of integration are defined by the cylinder
lets convert to cylindrical.

$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 \sqrt{(4r^2 + 1)} r \,dr \,d\theta\\
u = 4r^2 + 1\\
du = 8r dr\\
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^{17} \frac 18 \sqrt{u} \,du \,d\theta\\
\int_0^{2\pi} (\frac 18)(\frac23) u^{\frac32}  \,d\theta |_1^{17}\\
(2\pi)(\frac1{12})(17\sqrt{17}-1)
$

I get the same answer.

Comment: My professor. OMG!

Comment: I will delete this post. It is his fault.

Comment: @user3773246 Well, that quite settles it, does it not? ;)

Comment: hey @user_of_math, can u look over my solution??